# How to resolve "nuxt WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/ws' failed: Could not connect to the server."

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

When using Content in Nuxt 3, I encounter the following error. I am running it in a Docker environment and using Safari as my browser. What should I do?

nuxt WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/ws' failed: Could not connect to the server.

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:24678/_nuxt/' failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connecte

Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost. http://localhost:24678/_nuxt/

What I did is

```
 - 24678:24678
 - 4000:4000
```

in docker-compose.yml